# vendors~main.chunk.js file is getting downloaded multiple times

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, create-react-app, video.js

In our Create React App, this `vendors~main.chunk.js` file is getting downloaded multiple times.

We are using React 17, and previously, we got this issue when we assigned an `undefined` value to an `onHover` event listener.

Now, we are getting this again when we tried intercepting the network requests of [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/) using [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook/) like this

```
xhook.before(function(request: any) {
   const videoToken = localStorage.getItem('videoToken')
   if (!request.url.includes('token') && videoToken) {
      const newRequestUrl = `${request.url}?token=${videoToken}`
      request.url = newRequestUrl
   }
})
```

I have two questions

1. When and why will this file generally get downloaded (I know it contains the node modules, but I want to know what causes this to get downloaded)?
2. Is there anything specific to my implementation?

Please help me out, TIA.